# Edittext changing text which is clickable in android?

Tags: android-edittext

I found difficulty in changing text in Android.
My Problem is: I have a edit text name Password, it is disable and having some password eg, 123 when i enable that edittext having password it convert that in Reset Password text. 
Now i have to click on reset password it open a dialog box.
Now tell me how to change text after enabling which is clickable.

Comment: "Now tell me how to change text after enabling which is clickable." 
Now post your code.

Comment: pass_et.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                 if (status == false) {
                                  pass_et.setText("Reset Password");
                            status = true;
                           }
                                    return true; // return is important...
                                }
                            });

Comment: but this text is not clickable, tell me that, i want this